# cant find array inside array in javascript

Tags: javascript

this is the snippet: this code is not working, the problem it is not recognizing the array inside the array.

how can i improve it?

thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>The new ECMASCRIPT 5 method isArray returns true when used on an array.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function findApple(arr, item) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
       findApple(arr[i], item);
    }
    else if (arr[i] == "apple") {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
var one = ["apple", "apple", ["orange", "apple", "banana"]];

var data = findApple(one, "apple");
alert(data);
var item = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is here `findApple(arr[i], item);` - you're not using the return value.

Comment: `it is not recognizing the array inside the array` yeah, I don't think that is correct.

Comment: on a side note, shouldn't the apple in the else if be `item` otherwise there is no point in passing the `item` var in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following problem:

```
if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) { findApple(arr[i], item); }
```

As you wrote the script, you know that findApple RETURNS something. So the right syntax would be:

```
var result=findApple();
```

As you want to pass it back to the callee simply do:

```
 count+=result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `count += findApple(arr[i], item);`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findApple(arr, item) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
       count+=findApple(arr[i], item);
    }
    else if (arr[i] == "apple") {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
var one = ["apple", "apple", ["orange", "apple", "banana"]];

var data = findApple(one, "apple");
alert(data);
var item = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>The new ECMASCRIPT 5 method isArray returns true when used on an array.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>



</body>
</html>
```